# Agrupar elementos repetidos de una lista y sumar sus valores C#

Tags: c#, lista, agrupación

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
List<String> datos = new List<string>();
```

En ella guardo los siguientes datos:

```
  datos.Insert(0, nomMaterial); //Material1
  datos.Insert(1, "$" + costoMaterial);//500.00
  datos.Insert(2, areaCuadrada);//80m2
  datos.Insert(3, "$" + costoTotal);//40,000

  datos.Insert(0, nomMaterial);//Material2
  datos.Insert(1, "$" + costoMaterial);//200
  datos.Insert(2, areaCuadrada);//40m2
  datos.Insert(3, "$" + costoTotal);//8,000


  datos.Insert(0, nomMaterial);//Material1
  datos.Insert(1, "$" + costoMaterial);//500.00
  datos.Insert(2, areaCuadrada);//20m2
  datos.Insert(3, "$" + costoTotal);//10,000

  datos.Insert(0, nomMaterial);//Material2
  datos.Insert(1, "$" + costoMaterial);//200.00
  datos.Insert(2, areaCuadrada);//10m2
  datos.Insert(3, "$" + costoTotal);//2000
```

Me gustaría que por cada Material que se repita se sumen las cantidades para agruparlos y al final mostrar un resumen de ambos, ejemplo:

```
Material:Material1
Costo:500
SumaArea=100m2
SumaTotal=50,000

Material:Material2
Costo:200
SumaArea=50m2
SumaTotal=10,000
```

El costo de cada material siempre será el mismo, lo que me interesa es saber cómo agruparlos para obtener la suma de sus áreas y el precio total sin tener que mostrar uno por uno, espero haya sido claro, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! esto es una tarea de la uni? cuales son las reglas sobre que podes usar? que intentaste? porque llenas datos de esa forma? tu clase parece muy rara

Comment: Eso es muy sencillo con Linq. Revisa los métodos [GroupBy](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2) y [Sum](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7.2) por ejemplo

Comment: porque usas el Insert() para agregar los items en la lista ? puedes usar el Add()

Answer (score 3):

Para lograr lo que planteas deberias usar clases y no una lista de string, algo como ser

```
public class Material {
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
   public decimal Costo {get;set;}
   public int Area {get;set;}

   public decimal Total { 
       get { return this.Costo * this.Area; }
   }

 }
```

El total es una ropiedad de solo lectura donde realizas el calculo

Entonces agregas los items usando

```
List<Material> lista = new List<Material>();
Material m1 = new Material(){
    Nombre = "Material1",
    Costo = 500,
    Area = 80
};
lista.Add(m1);

Material m2 = new Material(){
    Nombre = "Material2",
    Costo = 200,
    Area = 40
};
lista.Add(m1);
```

Usando linq podras agrupar

```
var result = from item in lista
              group item by item.Nombre into g
              select new Material() {
                 Nombre = g.Key,
                 Costo = g.Sum(x=> x.Costo),
                 Area = g.Sum(x=>x.Area)
              };
```

para mostrarlo solo iteras el resultado del linq

```
foreach(var item in result){
   Console.WriteLine("Material:{0} SumaTotal:{1}", item.Material, item.Total)
}
```

como veras usando clases todo es mas simple